How to std::bind a function that in turn calls std::bind?
I thought I had a hold on std::bind, but the compiler has me stumped on this one. Currently compiling with c++17.
I have a generic way of binding a function to a bunch of arguments so that it can be called later with no arguments. This is NoParameterBinding, works fine.
I have a generic way of binding a function to a bunch of arguments, leaving the first argument open with std::placeholders. This is SingleParameterBinding, works fine.
An intermediate static struct is now going to do some calls for me. I pass it the same arguments I would pass SingleParameterBinding, and it forwards the arguments. This is BindRequest::bindOnce, works fine.
Lastly, I want to package that last function up using NoParameterBinding. BindRequest::bindTwice will do this for me. It calls NoParameterBinding, passes the bindOnce function, and forwards the arguments. This fails.
What gives? I'm passing a function along with all the arguments it needs, but the compiler insists it can't convert things to std::function<void()>:

forwarding.cpp:10:38: error: conversion from ‘std::_Bind_helper<false, void (&)(void (&)(const long int&, const double&), double&&), void (&)(const long int&, const double&), double>::type’ to non-scalar type ‘NoParameterBinding::Task’ {aka ‘std::function<void()>’} requested

Here is the code in question:
#include<functional>

struct NoParameterBinding
{
        using Task = std::function<void()>;

        template<typename FuncType, typename... Args>
            static void bind(FuncType&& func, Args&&... args)
            {
                Task task = std::bind(std::forward<FuncType>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            }
};

struct SingleParameterBinding
{
        using CallbackType = std::function<void(long)>;

        template<typename FuncType, typename... Args>
            static void bind(FuncType&& callbackFunc, Args&&... args)
            {
                CallbackType callback = std::bind(std::forward<FuncType>(callbackFunc), std::placeholders::_1, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            }

};

struct BindRequest
{
        using CallbackType = SingleParameterBinding::CallbackType;

        template<typename CallbackFuncType, typename... CallbackArgs>
            static void bindOnce(CallbackFuncType&& callback, CallbackArgs&&... callbackArgs)
            {
                SingleParameterBinding::bind(std::forward<CallbackFuncType>(callback), std::forward<CallbackArgs>(callbackArgs)...);
            }

        template<typename CallbackFuncType, typename... CallbackArgs>
            static void bindTwice(CallbackFuncType&& callback, CallbackArgs&&... callbackArgs)
            {
                NoParameterBinding::bind(BindRequest::bindOnce<CallbackFuncType, CallbackArgs...>, std::forward<CallbackFuncType>(callback), std::forward<CallbackArgs>(callbackArgs)...);
            }
};

void exampleCallback(const long& l, const double& d)
{
    return;
}

int main()
{
    NoParameterBinding::bind(exampleCallback,'a',9.9);
    SingleParameterBinding::bind(exampleCallback, 9.9);
    BindRequest::bindOnce(exampleCallback, 9.9);
    BindRequest::bindTwice(exampleCallback, 9.9); //Why freak out here?
    return 0;
}


The typical workaround when struggling with std::bind is to use lambdas (which IMO should be the default).

Perhaps that is the answer. I got it to compile by passing  a lambda that does my call instead of forwarding arguments. NoParameterBinding::bind([&]{bindOnce(callback, callbackArgs...);});. Still, I'll leave this up because I don't understand what's wrong with the code.

std::bind has a special case for when its argument is itself a bind expression. Say you have template <typename callable> void f(callable g) - a function that expects a callable as a parameter. std::bind(f, g)() is equivalent to f(g) for any callable g - except the callable that is itself produced by another std::bind call. Then it's f(g()) and would likely fail to compile. This basically makes std::bind unusable in generic code - it tends to choke when the caller passes a bind expression.

You could bypass this behavior by wrappring the output of std:bind into, say, std::function before passing it along to another std::bind. But that of course adds run-time overhead.
